# How to add uncompiled .mlmodel to Xcode UnitTests bundle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, coreml, mlmodel

I need to add a .mlmodel file to my Unit Tests in order to check programmatic model compilation in my framework. But, since version 12, Xcode automatically compiles any .mlmodel file added to the project and replaces it with .mlmodelc which is unwanted in this context.

So, if I add a `TestModel.mlmodel` to the project, I can't get a resource URL:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:ModelTest.class];

// modelURL is nil
NSURL *modelURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"TestModel" 
                           withExtension:@"mlmodel"];
```

If I open the compiled bundle package I can see `TestModel.mlmodelc` there.

How can I disable automatic CoreML model compilation in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

When the project is selected in the **Project navigator**, all compiled files can be found in the Compile Source section of the **Build Phases** tab. Can you find the file there ? If yes, you can just remove it.

When the file is selected in the **Project navigator**, you can do the same from the **Target Membership** section of the **File Inspector**  : if the box beside the name of your target is checked, uncheck it.

Finally if you want this file to be added to the resources of your application, you probably have to add it to the **Copy Bundle Resource** section of the Build Phase tab (or you can create a specific Copy File Phase for it)

Comment: This doesn't work. If I remove TestModel.mlmodel from Compile Sources and add it to Copy Bundle Resources it eventually getting compiled to .mlmodelc, anyway.

Comment: It seems that Xcode recognizes the file as a compilable resource (as it does for XIB). You should try to remove the file from Copy Bundle Resources and add it to a new Copy Phase section instead (with Resources for destination). If it doesn't work, you could also copy it 'manually' using a little bash script.  The goal is to prevent Xcode from handling the file.

Answer (score -1):

Why do not you load it directly?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/downloading_and_compiling_a_model_on_the_user_s_device

```
static func loadModel(from path: URL, demo: Bool = false) async throws -> MLModel? {
    let modelConfiguration = MLModelConfiguration()
    // the file is already handled by copying resources in Xcode: -> mlmodelc (compiled)
    let compiledModelURL = demo ? path : try await MLModel.compileModel(at: path)

    return try MLModel(contentsOf: compiledModelURL, configuration: modelConfiguration)
}
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question. I don't ask how to load the model, I wanted to prevent automatic model compiling.