# Do not compile MLModel in Swift Package Bundle

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, coreml

I want to add a .mlmodel to my swift package to have a test to verify that the compilation is working.

```
targets: [
    .target(
      name: "packageName",
      dependencies: ["package1"]
    ),
    .testTarget(
      name: "packageNameTests",
      dependencies: ["packageName"],
      resources: [
        .copy("Resources/testmodel.mlmodel"),
      ]
    )
  ]
```

My problem is the .mlmodel is always as a compiled model after bundling

```
let docsPath = Bundle.module.resourcePath!
let docsArray = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: docsPath)
    print(docsArray)
```

leads to ["testmodel.mlmodelc"]

I am excepting testmodel.mlmodel to be present instead. I find it strange that copy is processing the ressource. Is there a workaround ? I am using Xcode 14 beta but there is a similar post on StackOverflow without answer regarding this issue [How to add uncompiled .mlmodel to Xcode UnitTests bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64298356/how-to-add-uncompiled-mlmodel-to-xcode-unittests-bundle) that got this problem with Xcode 12

Thank you

Comment: If the compiled model exists and works, wouldn't that tell you it was compiled correctly?

Comment: I want to do this to provide unit test with the package. I can't provide an unit test for compilation if I'm unable to bundle the .mlmodel before compilation

Answer (score -1):

Apple allows you to download and compile a `MLModel` on the fly.

So if you use a URL for your `MLModel`, you should be able to compile it following this Apple [guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/downloading_and_compiling_a_model_on_the_user_s_device).

```
let compiledModelURL = try MLModel.compileModel(at: modelDescriptionURL)
let model = try MLModel(contentsOf: compiledModelURL)
```

Comment: It was maybe not clear but I want to do this to provide unit test with the package. I can't provide an unit test for compilation if I'm unable to bundle the .mlmodel before compilation

Comment: I would be surprised if you can't write a test unit that uses URLs.